Identify this crime drama with strong female lead
I have been Googling for a good 20-30 minutes and cannot find it. 
The show is set in Appalachia (West Virginia?) and features a crime family with a 50+ year old female as the head of the family. A mining company is trying to buy rights so that they can get access to mine the mountain, but the family is trying to stop them. I think it was airing pretty recently within 5 years, I'd say.
Anyone know what it is called?

I think this is the FX network's Justified, specifically season 2 (2011).  Wikipedia
describes the story arc for the season:

Season two deals primarily with the criminal dealings of the Bennett clan. Family matriarch Mags Bennett (Margo Martindale) and her three sons Dickie (Jeremy Davies), Coover (Brad William Henke), and Doyle (Joseph Lyle Taylor) plan to expand their marijuana business into Crowder territory following Bo's death, as Boyd is reluctant to follow in his father's footsteps. Raylan gets involved in the struggle between the two criminal organizations, and because of a long-standing feud between the Givens and Bennett families, things start to get complicated with their past catching up with them. Meanwhile, an effort by a mining conglomerate to secure access rights to the mountain gets Raylan and Boyd involved on opposite sides of the operation and provokes local backlash against the Bennetts.

